# How to add document Id in the document in firestore database in flutter application

Tags: firebase, flutter, google-cloud-firestore

I am using below code to add document in firestore collection in a flutter application. I am not getting an idea that on how to add the document id in the document. Please guide me

```
    Firestore.instance.collection("posts1").add({
                    //"id": "currentUser.user.uid",
                    "postTitle": posttitle.text,
                    "postcategory": selectedCategory,
                    "post_id":documentId,
                      })
                      .then((result) =>
                  {print("success")}
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Use [`document()`](https://pub.dev/documentation/cloud_firestore/latest/cloud_firestore/CollectionReference/document.html) with no arguments to first generate a reference to a document with a random ID, then use [`setData()`](https://pub.dev/documentation/cloud_firestore/latest/cloud_firestore/DocumentReference/setData.html) to create it and add the [`documentID`](https://pub.dev/documentation/cloud_firestore/latest/cloud_firestore/DocumentReference/documentID.html) as part of the new document:

```dart
final DocumentReference ref = 
    FirebaseFirestore.instance.collection("posts1").doc();

await ref.setData({
  "post_id": ref.documentID,
  // ... add more fields here
});
```

Answer (score -1):

`DocumentReference docRef = await  Firestore.instance.collection("products").add({`

```
 'description': product.description,
 'imageUrl': product.imageUrl,
 'price': product.price,
});
final newProduct = Product(
 title: product.title,
 description: product.description,
 price: product.price,
 imageUrl: product.imageUrl,
 id:docRef.documentID,
);

_items.add(newProduct);
```

Comment: this is adding the entry twice with different id, 'Doug Stevenson' solution is the correct one, just change the DocumentReference ref = Firestore.instance.collection("posts1").document(); to: DocumentReference ref = Firestore.instance.collection("posts1").add({});